# Actionbar using Actionbar sherlock not showing both icon and text for actionitems in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

```
package com.actionbarapp.in;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        menu.add("Settings")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.settings)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        menu.add("Help").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_help)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        menu.add("Reports")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.reports)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}![enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS| MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

if you want to show, always, the item as a button.

If you are using the split action bar ("splitActionBarWhenNarrow" in manifest), then you can't show both in the same time.
The only way to achieve that would be to use a custom view...

Comment: it doesnt work on android platform 2.3 it only show icon not the text for actionitem

Comment: Check issue: [link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/400) "You will never see both the icon and text on small views on any screen with a width less than 480dp. That is a rule from the native action bar."